# Planting grass during shmita

Tags: halacha, agriculture, shmita

Is it permissible to plant grass during the *shmita* year?

As [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32016/rambam-on-planting-non-fruit-trees-on-shemita) indicates, there is a *machloket* regarding planting non-fruit trees during *shmita*. If grass is like a tree, it would be subject to that (we *pasken* that it's *assur*). But if it's not a tree, we might be  more *meikel*, and allow it (either *l'chatchila* or at least *b'dieved*).

Comment: Unclear what you're asking! The answers in the question you refer to clearly say that we don't pasken like the opinion - רשב"ג - who could possibly allow it.

Comment: @Danny But still, grass might not be subject to that at all if it isn't a tree.

Comment: but why would grass be permitted if non-fruit trees are forbidden? (Unless you want a theoretical discussion as to what the opinion of רשב"ג would be.) IOW, Once we pasken that it's forbidden, the "other" opinion becomes theoretical/invalidated. and it's incorrect to call it a "machloket". (Unless you have a reliable Posek that contradicts the Rambam who "invalidated" the other opinion.)

Comment: Unless you mean that grass would be "even easier" than non-fruit trees?

Comment: Yes, grass might be permissible even if non-fruit-trees aren't, because they don't even resemble trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [shmita gardening guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20140626053752/http://dat.gov.il/NR/rdonlyres/6F3D9CAB-5647-449D-8E73-C74649C3C671/0/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9F%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94.pdf) from the Israeli Religions Ministry, it seems that grass should be planted at least a month before *shmita* starts, as with a tree. They even recommend having it in before Tammuz, if i understand correctly. (See page 25 of linked document).

Comment: (1) How'd you find that guide? (2) Do you know what their sources for this are?

Comment: If i happen to find the answer, of course i'll come back and share it. [I've done it before.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/39069/5151)

Comment: 1) My mother found it actually, and she sent it to me. 2) I looked, but they didn't provide for that claim. Nonetheless, it has approbations from the chief rabbis, so i'm inclined to trust it.

Comment: That's a good reason to trust it.

Answer (score 1):

For further sources, R Yosef Tzvi Rimon in his (highly recommended) [reference book on shmita](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592642578) adresses this question indirectly and writes (pp. 34-35)

> Since the Sages permitted labors that are forbidden by rabbinic decree
>   in cases of financial loss, it is permitted to water one's garden when
>   necessary (but less frequently than usual) [...] Generally speaking, a
>   private garden can be maintained even without performing any other
>   labor, and **therefore they are forbidden**.

He holds that the prohibition of planting applies even to plants that do not bear fruit (p. 42 and 89) - [see this other question for the background](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592642578)

He later writes (p. 44)

> One may perform labors that are generally forbidden by rabbinic
>   decrees **only when failure to do so will cause the plants to die**